# Mathville sunrise modeling problem?

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

In Mathville, the time for the sunrise for any day during the year can be modeled by the formula;

$$t=1.15\sin\bigg[\frac{2\pi}{365}(d-74)\bigg]+7$$

where $t$ is the time in hours after midnight and $d$ is the number of days in the year (excluding leap year).

What are the earliest and latest sunrise times (in Hr:Min format) during year 1 ?

**My approach:**

Should I be using the derivative to find the least and the greatest value of $t$, then finding the critical points, and then the second derivative?

Comment: You can certainly use the derivative, but a better way is to think about when the sine function is maximised (and minimised). Can you think of a point where the sine function is equal to 1? When does that happen?

A further hint: try graphing the function.

Comment: The max of sin is 1. Its min is -1.

Comment: Correct. Can you find $d$ such that the sine value is $1$ (or $-1$)?

Comment: Yes, I can. For max, $d=165.25$.

Comment: But I think I need to calculate $t$ and not $d$. As per my calculations, $t_{min}=05:51$. Is it so?

Comment: Correct. You can similarly find $t_{max}$. The reason I asked you to find $d$ is that we want to make sure that it's even possible to obtain the minimum value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights.